# Is it possible to embed the Google Maps WebGL 3D globe in your site?

Tags: google-maps, webgl

At https://www.google.com/maps/preview/?force=webgl you get a 3D WebGL globe if you select satellite view and zoom out.

Is it possible to embed this globe on your own site using the Google Maps API? So far I haven't found any references that suggest this is possible.

Comment: welp - it probably is for the moment, but once they [cut off the API](http://www.gearthblog.com/blog/archives/2014/12/google-earth-api-deprecated.html), it won't...(?)